# The JSON value could not be converted to vdm_web_api.Logics.Film

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

I am currently developing a c# ASP .NET Core api using MongoDB.

What i want to do is POST a new film item in my dataBase.

This is my film's Logic:

```
{
    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class Film
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }   // usefull to get the id as a string and not as an object

        [BsonElement("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("length")]
        public int Length { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("thumbnailLink")]
        public string ThumbnailLink { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("synopsis")]
        public string Synopsis { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("type")]
        public string Type{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

and there's the Post function in my film's controller:
[EDIT] i added 'await' as Crowcoder recommended

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Film>> Create([FromBody] Film film)
{
    await _filmCollection.InsertOneAsync(film);
    return CreatedAtRoute("Get", new { id = film.Id.ToString() }, film);
}
```

At the moment, i'm using Postman to test it.

here is a screen shot of my glorious status 400...[image: screenshot of postman]

-> Or in text: HTTP

```
POST /api/films/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5001
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 521

{
    "title": "Armagedon",
    "length": 169,
    "thumbnailLink": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a4/The_Artist_Poster.jpg",
    "synopsis": "blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla",
    "type": "film"
}
```

Can someone explain me what and why am i doing wrong?
I hope i was clear in this post, i'm not frequently posting on stackOverflow.
Thank you, and have a nice day! :)

Comment: Not saying this is the reason for the Bad Request, but you should be `await`ing the call to `InsertOneAysnc`. You will be returning from the controller and breaking down the Request before the insert can happen.

Comment: ok i did this: ```public async Task<ActionResult<Film>> Create([FromBody] Film film)
        {
            await _filmCollection.InsertOneAsync(film);

            return CreatedAtRoute("Get", new { id = film.Id.ToString() }, film);
        }``` but it still doesn't works as you said. Anyway thanks for the tip

Comment: Your screenshot is somewhat obscured, but it looks like you are posting a json array? Your controller is not expecting that.

Comment: I'am very new to c#, asp.net core and mongodb so i followed an unclear tutorial. What am i supposed to do here? I thougt [FromBody] will "convert" my json array to the Film logic class

Comment: If you pass a json array it will only work if you are taking an array or list of the object. Change your request body so it is not an array - remove the `[` and `]`.

Comment: Ok thanks that seems logic. however, now i have a 500 internal server error: ```fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.```

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the entire POST body json as text instead of screenshot? You can even use Postman code generator to post the entire HTTP request

Comment: I think your 500 error is related to how you craft your CreatedAtRoute. Are you sure that is correct for how you have configured the GET action?

Comment: I have 2 get actions, 1 to get all movies, the other to get one by its id  ```[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Film>> GetAllFilms()
        {
            //return all films -> needs to add a compagny selector
            var toReturn =  await _filmCollection.Find(_ => true).ToListAsync();
            return toReturn;
        }
        [HttpGet("{_id}")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Film>> GetFilmById(string _id)
        {
            var toReturn = await _filmCollection.Find(item => item.Id == _id).ToListAsync();
            return toReturn;
        }```